# reverse linked list - Recursion

Tags: recursion, singly-linked-list

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I am just trying to learn recursion.

The below code can reverse a linked list.

I understand the logic until line 3, but I am confused when line 4 will be called `(n.next=prev)` since the function gets called again before executing this line.

Can someone let me know the flow of this recursion?

```
 void reverse(node n, node prev) {
     if (n == null) { newroot = prev; return; }
     reverse(n.next, n);
     n.next = prev;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code from, out of interest? I can't see how line 4 would run either. Line 2 is the base case, and it returns something, and so line 3 will always block until it returns something. Is there some threading going on that isn't apparent?

Comment: The code is from http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7787672

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure. +1 for the question.

Comment: I would walk through the code with simple examples. First, with an empty list. Then, with a list with one element. Then, with a list with two elements. If you understand that, you should be able to understand all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as **n** hits `null`  and reverse function `return` it will backtrack from there to it's calling function all the way to it's first calling function.

UPDATE: *See the comments below for a more complete explanation.*

Comment: sorry missed that, was busy explaining the flow of recursion. As I have figured it out, as there is no return statement in it function will execute (while backtracking) `n.next = prev;` after  `reverse(n.next, n);` releasing control to calling function.

Comment: As I read it, every time line three calls `reverse`, it blocks until one of the recursive calls gets passed an `n` that's equal to `null`. That last function call will return nothing ~ presumably a `null` value, I don't know what language this is. That recoils back to the first instance of `reverse`, which, still stuck at line 3, now evaluates, returning nothing, having never allowed line 4 to execute. I think that's how me and Learner both see it. I don't see how line 4 gets executed?

Comment: see when first time the function returns, it returns back to 3rd line, then it executes 4th one and as function is done executing itself, it's control returns to calling function 3rd line , then it executes 4th line and so on.... until final parent function executes.

Comment: Sorry. I get it now. I saw line 3 working as though it read `return reverse(n.next, n);`. My bad. Cheers.

Comment: @Carl Smith,  recursion is tricky sometimes, even to skilled programmers !

Comment: So just to confirm I understood the flow...This is more like invoking a function and then incrementing a variable and passing this new value again to that function and so on....